# How to convert Degree to polar coordinates in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I draw a circle in UILabel. I set start degree and end degree for circle. Now I want to add imageview to this circle label that polar coordinates of Imageview match with end degree of cirle. So that, I want to convert end degree of circle to polar coordinates. Example:

```
Width of UILabel = 62
Height of UILabe = 62
Start degree of cirle in UILabel  = 0 (degree)
End degree of cirle in UILabel  = 150 (degree)
```

I added UIImageView(pointImgView) to this UILabel as below

```
  UIImageView *pointImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 6, 6)];
 [self addSubview:pointImgView];
```

I don't know how to convert End degree of cirle (150 degree) to polar coordinates of pointImgView.

Please give me some advices. Thanks so much

Comment: I believe you're looking for polar coordinates, not radians, and have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: @cincodenada: Yes, thanks. I need to convert to polar coordinates. Thanks much

Comment: What maths have you looked for to help you?

Answer (score 3):

Use these macros.

```
#define kDCControlDegreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
#define kDCControlRadiansToDegrees(x) ((x) * 180.0 / M_PI)
```

**Notes for Code standard :** If you use this calculation in entire app, use this macro. If you use it in one place, better write one method in your viewcontroller using this logic.

**Updated:**

My suggestion : Instead of use image view, fill label color with image my `backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` and draw circle around label by below code.
Use below code to draw circle with `start` angle.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect boundsRect = self.bounds;
    float x = boundsRect.size.width / 2;
    float y = boundsRect.size.height / 2;
    boundsRect.size.width -= 5;
    boundsRect.size.height -= 5;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.valueArcWidth);
    [self.trackingColor set];
    // Drawing code
    CGFloat valueAdjusted = (self.value - self.minimumValue) / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue);
    CGContextAddArc(context,
                    x,
                    y,
                    boundsRect.size.width / 2 -2,
                    kDCControlDegreesToRadians(self.arcStartAngle ,
                    kDCControlDegreesToRadians(self.arcStartAngle + (360 * valueAdjusted),
                    0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Here `MinimumValue = 10.0` and `maximum value = 11.0`, and your value must be between in between(10 -11). that is convert your value into 0.0 to 1.0 and add it to 10.0. 
Note: I give my code , edit it according to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, but exactly I want to convert degree to polar coordinates. Please updated your answer. thanks much

Comment: Your code will convert to polar coordinates? I see it convert to radian. is it right?

Comment: No. It won't. I give solution according to your question. Just try it if you want.

Comment: I want to draw as image at here : http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3782/o27w.png. I want to add point green color at end point progress. I used KAProgressLabel library.

Comment: Did you want to add slider and drag this slider to change circle ?

Comment: No, i dont want to add slider. I only want to add green end point to current Circle. Can you help me? Thanks so much

Comment: Then You can do simply. Just create subclass of UILabel and override `drawRect:` with above code? class should have variable what you have used in drawRect:. One doubt, You haven't use slider then why do you drag polar point?

Comment: Can you support how to get polar coordinates of 180 degree?

Answer (score 1):

Just define a macro like:

```
#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

And change your method like:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(360), 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: @thanks. but i edited my question, exactly i want to convert degree to polar coordinates. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the below methods for the conversion

```
#include <math.h>               // M_PI

float RadiantoDegree(float radian)
{
    return ((radian / M_PI) * 180.0f);
}

float DegreetoRadian(float degree)
{
    return ((degree / 180.0f) * M_PI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula

```
radian = degree*M_PI/180
```

where your angle is in `degree` and output is in `radian`. You can either define a function or macro for this.